# IP Routes to connect to every subnets in the local network

Tags: networking, router, ip, routing

I have an ethernet only network.
I don't know the IPs and the subnets used by some devices so I can't setup my computer to connect to those devices.
I have used tools like masscan to create a map of the network using ARP but it takes ages (even connecting the devices directly together by ethernet).

Would it be possible to create IP routes to get all the packets in my local network without changing the IP address and the subnet ?

I was thinking of something like that:

```
# Enable packets forwarding
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

# Set local IP
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0

# Add IP routes for each subnet
ip route add 0.0.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.0
ip route add 0.0.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.0
...
ip route add 10.0.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.0
ip route add 10.0.2.0/24 via 192.168.1.0
...
ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 via 192.168.1.0
...
ip route add 255.255.255.0/24 via 192.168.1.0
```

Would that work or do I completely misunderstood the way it works ?

Comment: Adding a schema that describes your network, with routers indicated, could help us understand your situation.

Comment: My network don't have a particular structure. The pointis to create an ethernet device that will scan the local network until it finds a ModBus server to conntect to. The modbus TCP server can be on any subnet that the customer does not even know.

Comment: That sounds an extremely bad idea, because you also don't know whether there's exactly one ModBus server on the network, or whether there are three, or whether the network is full of hosts that are _not_ ModBus servers (and probing all of them might take a long time, all other issues aside)... and frankly, if the customer doesn't know what subnet the devices are on, it sounds like they're not the customer's devices in the first place and said customer shouldn't be attempting to access them?

Comment: Some clarity on what you're trying to achieve may produce more useful answers - at present, you've proposed a flawed solution to a very odd-sounding problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Would it be possible to create IP routes to get all the packets in my local network without changing the IP address and the subnet ?

No, routes will not help you *get* all the packets. They only help you *send* packets, but have no effect on receiving them. More generally, claiming to be a "router" (ip_forward=1) **will not automatically attract packets towards you** regardless of any subnet configuration.

A router only receives packets because hosts are specifically configured to use it – it doesn't just vacuum all packets, but still receives *only* those packets that have *the router's MAC address* on them, as hosts specifically address those packets to the router's MAC.

(On most modern Ethernets, MAC frames are switched – they are no longer visible to all hosts but are only delivered to the one device that has the specified destination MAC address. So if the ModBus server in question has a route like "default via 192.168.7.1", it will look up the MAC address of 192.168.7.1 and will only send stuff there.)

If you are *already* receiving the packets on your network interface, you don't need any of this configuration – you can just see them in tcpdump. Most likely you're *not* receiving the packets, so the routes on your side can't do anything with packets that aren't there.

So in short, no, it won't work at all.

---

As a side note:

- When you're configuring a "local" or "interface" route on Linux, the preferred way to write it is `10.0.1.0/24 dev eth0`, *not* `10.0.1.0/24 via <my_own_ip>`. The latter may still work but is rather foreign to the Linux configuration (I believe it's an ancient BSD-ism).
- Subnets **do not have to be /24's.** If you want to cover all of 10.0.0.0/8, for example, you could just have the entire /8 as a single subnet instead of enumerating all 65536 possible /24's. If you wanted to cover every possible address, you could just have a /0 route (i.e. a "default route").

  The only practical difference is positive – all those "10.x.x.0" and "10.x.x.255" addresses in the middle are now perfectly valid host addresses in the middle of an /8 instead of being reserved parts of a /24. (And this only applies to "direct" subnet routes, anyway. Gateway or "via" routes don't have anything reserved.)
- Several large chunks of addresses are unusable for various reasons and wouldn't need to be listed, as there is no chance your device would be using them. For example, 0.0.0.0/8 is reserved for historical reasons; 224.0.0.0/4 is used for multicast and cannot be used for normal subnets; and all of 240.0.0.0/4 (i.e. all the way up to 255.255.255.255!) is *practically* reserved, with perhaps only 2-3 networks in the world using it.